# What is the difference between saturation and brightness?

Tags: colors, color-theory

In Colors theory, what is the difference between saturation and brightness?

Comment: Sounds like a designer question, which is better asked at http://doctype.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about color theory, not programming. You may try the [graphicdesign.se] site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point rattling off another 1-line answer because it's a rather large topic.

Wikipedia has this for [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Next there's an brief tutorial on [Color Theory](http://ilab.usc.edu/wiki/index.php/HSV_And_H2SV_Color_Space). Finally more on [HSV And H2SV Color Space](http://colortheory.liquisoft.com/) with some transformation code in C++.